# Spring Boot: Deploy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat, развертывание

Заказал vps на reg.ru под ubunt'ой. Из под консоли с помощью ssh вошел на 'сервер' и вижу перед собой пустое пост-пространство, а что дальше?

Распишите, пожалуйста, вкратце пошаговое руководство.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В **pom.xml** нужна зависимость и тип упаковки:

   ```
   <packaging>war</packaging>

   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. В главном классе(у меня *main.java*) нужно наследоваться от `SpringBootServletInitializer` и переопределить метод `configure()`:

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class TaskApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

       @Override
       protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure 
                (SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {

           return builder.sources(TaskApplication.class);
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(TaskApplication.class, args);
       }
   }
   ```
3. С помощью maven последовательно выполнить `clean` и `package`. На выходе в директории *target* должен появиться **.war** файл(у меня он называется **task-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war**).
4. Далее нам понадобится обычный удаленный сервер с ОС Ubunta, можно без домена.
5. У меня стоит Linux поэтому инструкция будет по нему: открываем терминал, присоединяемся к удаленному серверу с помощью `ssh login@ip`, и вводим пароль который нам предоставили на сервисе.[image]
6. Обновляем систему `sudo apt-update`, `sudo apt-upgrade`.
7. Скачиваем jre `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless`.
8. Устанавливаем tomcat `sudo apt install tomcat8`.
9. Изменяем файл `vi /etc/tomcat8/tomcat-users.xml`: добавляем строчку `<user username="root" password="password" roles="manager-gui"/>` в самый низ перед закрывающим тэгом.[image]
10. Перезагружаем tomcat `sudo systemctl restart tomcat8`.
11. Открываем браузер, пишем в строку поиска *ip-сервера:8080/manager/html* и вводим данные которые писали в строке файла из пункта 9.
12. После входа можно смело загружать наш **.war** файл и жать deploy.

После деплоя наши файлы будут находиться в */var/lib/tomcat8/webapps*.

Вероятно, вы как и я, захотите запускать свое приложение из-под корня, тогда вам следует потратить еще немного времени:

1. На сервере с томкатом переходим в папку с нашими проектами `cd /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps` и удаляем директорию ROOT с помощью `rm -r ROOT`.
2. Создаем директорию заново `mkdir ROOT`.
3. Открываем у себя на компьютере терминал и пишем `sudo scp <путь к .war> login@ip:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps`. Должно получиться что то вроде такого.

[image]

> Если будете получать ошибку "Страница недоступна" или подобную ей,
> попробуйте перезагрузить сервер на хостинге.